# Accessing SQL Server from the Internet/Intranet

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I'm a total n00b when it comes to SQL Server admin stuff, so sorry if this is basic.  I've designed a website in C#/asp.net with a SQL Server backend on my local machine.  Runs perfectly when I open the site through VS2010 and run it.  However, when I publish it and try to run the site, the ASPX works fine but it can't connect to the data.  I can't log in, and the dropdowns which should be auto-populated are empty.

I'm assuming this has something to do with permissions?  Can anyone help me?

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 and Visual Studio 2010.  I just want to test this out before I upload it to a server I have to pay for.

Comment: First of all check your `connection string`. `(localhost)` is a devil ;)

Comment: <add name="OLDSiteConn" connectionString="Data Source=old-tyme\monarch;Initial Catalog=Monarch;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165718%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: Have you tried debugging to see what errors you may be getting when it tries to connect?

Answer (score 0):

Is the connection string correct? Is the SQL Server reachable from the webserver where you published the website?

Comment: It's on a PC.  Running WinXP.  Yes, I know I shouldn't do that but it's just for testing.  As I said, I can run it fine from Visual Studio, but it will not connect to the data when I run it as 192.168.x.x.  The ASP loads, but no data is brought in.

Comment: what is your connection string?

Comment: <add name="OLDSiteConn" connectionString="Data Source=old-tyme\monarch;Initial Catalog=Monarch;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

Answer (score 0):

From your comment - you are using `Integrated Security=True`. In this case IIS logins to SQL server with Application Pool's user. So it looks like this user doesn't have appropriate permissions. Try to use Sql Server authentication (use login and password in connection string). Or, as an option - check out user (app pool's advanced settings) and add it to sql server with appropriate permissions.